# OpenCV FileStorage to store in yml in directory other than that of project

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to store a `yml` file using `FileStorage` into the `D:\` directory but it keeps storing it in the project directory.. Any help??

This is the code I use:

```
cv:: String outputFile = "D:\output.yml";

cv::FileStorage fstest2(outputFile, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
```

I am working with (c++/cli) in windows..

Thanks

Comment: "D:\output.yml"; Maybe you should escape that or use / instead of \

Comment: That worked.. thanks a lot :)